# Hiding a member from .NET code but not from COM

Tags: .net, interop, com-interop

Is it possible to make a member of a class visible to COM only i.e. not to managed code?  Here's a concrete example:

Say I have a `Widget` class with a `DateSubmitted` property which is a nullable date (i.e. `DateTime?`); it might not have been "submitted" yet and thus the `DateSubmitted` value could be `null`.  When I reference my assembly from another managed assembly, I want to use this property.  However, when I reference my assembly from a COM environment (e.g. VBA), the property won't be available because COM doesn't know anything about nullable types in .NET.

Ideally, I want to have another property that is just a normal "Date" type so it's visible to COM and possibly a boolean flag to indicate to COM API users when the date is null, and I don't want those properties to be available in .NET.

I guess what I'm wondering is whether there's an attribute or something, maybe somewhere in `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, that will allow me to effectively hide a member from .NET but make it available in COM.

Comment: I think you mean the other way around: you want to hide a member from being COM Visible but still visible in .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, members must be *public* to be usable from a COM server.  It is a fairly simple workaround, the COM client only ever sees the interface, the .NET programmer sees the class.  So you can expose the DateTime method in the interface and implement it explicitly in the class so it not public.  And provide a public version with the DateTime? argument in the class.

Also keep in mind that you hide a method from the COM client by giving it the [ComVisible(false)] attribute.  You can hide a method from the .NET programmer by giving it the [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] attribute.  That hides it in the IntelliSense popup.